# Create Relationship Between All Elements in an Array SQL query.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got an array of names:

```
 $names = array('ray'=>0,'bob'=>1,'sue'=>2,'jeff'=>3);
```

Then I have a table that stores relationships between each keyword in the array:

```
+----------+----------+
|  id_a    |   id_b   |
+----------+----------+
|   0      |    1     |
+----------+----------+
|   0      |    2     |
+----------+----------+
|   0      |    3     |
+----------+----------+
|   1      |    2     |
+----------+----------+
|   1      |    3     |
+----------+----------+
|   2      |    3     |
+----------+----------+
```

At the moment my function to store the relationships is:

```
    foreach($names as $name=>$id_a){
        foreach($names as $n2=>$id_b){
            if($name != $n2){
                INSERT INTO relationships (id_a,id_b) VALUES ($id_a,$id_b);
            }
        }
        array_shift($names);
    }
```

I'm wondering if there is a faster SQL solution to handle this type of action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the inserted values array first, then insert it all with [a single query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html); that'd be faster. The query would look like...

```
INSERT INTO relationships (id_a, id_b) VALUES (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3);
```

Comment: just like that, eh?  I'm going to keep the question open to see if I might elicit another option.  However, I am up-voting you and saying thank you, I look forward to trying out this solution.